# Arranging blocks with jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div.content` and there are 30 divs inside that (`div.blocks`)

I want to make an animation to `div.blocks` that come and go to their own position.

for example:

**CSS**

```
.content{
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.blocks{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    background:wheat;
    color:gray;
    font-size:large;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:4px; 
}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="blocks" data-number="0">1</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="1">2</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="2">3</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="3">4</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="4">5</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="5">6</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="6">7</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="7">8</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="8">9</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="9">10</div>
</div>
```

---

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
    // [0][0]==top
    // [0][1]=right
    var positions=[
    [10,10],
    [10,64],
    [10,118],
    [10,172],    
    [10,226],    

    [64,10],
    [64,64],
    [64,118],
    [64,172],    
    [64,226]    

    ];


    $( ".blocks" ).each(function() {
         var number=($(this).data('number'));
        $(this).animate({
            top:positions[number][0],
            right:positions[number][1]
        });
    });
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xnf7be8o/1/)

It is working well, But I want animation runs one by one (*when one animation completed **callback***), I mean when first `.blocks` arrived to `right:10` and `top:10` then run other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) feature.

```
$(".blocks").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(index * 500).animate({ ... });
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    // [0][0]==top
    // [0][1]=right
    var positions=[
    [10,10],
    [10,64],
    [10,118],
    [10,172],    
    [10,226],    
      
    [64,10],
    [64,64],
    [64,118],
    [64,172],    
    [64,226]    
    
    ];

    
    $( ".blocks" ).each(function(index) {
         var number=($(this).data('number'));
        $(this).delay(500 * index).animate({
            top:positions[number][0],
            right:positions[number][1]
        });
    });
})
```

```css
.content{
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.blocks{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    background:wheat;
    color:gray;
    font-size:large;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:4px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="blocks" data-number="0">1</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="1">2</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="2">3</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="3">4</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="4">5</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="5">6</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="6">7</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="7">8</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="8">9</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="9">10</div>
</div>
```

By default, I believe animations are 600ms, but as personal preference, I delay by 500 (to me it looks smoother).  Multiplying that by the index means you can "schedule" all the blocks to move when the script runs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use setInterval() function to call your function 
Here is my code

```js
$(function(){
    // [0][0]==top
    // [0][1]=right
    function Typer(callback)
    {
        var positions=[
            [10,10],
            [10,64],
            [10,118],
            [10,172],    
            [10,226],    
              
            [64,10],
            [64,64],
            [64,118],
            [64,172],    
            [64,226]    
            
        ];
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var div = $('[data-number="'+i+'"]');
            div.animate({
                top:positions[i][0],
                right:positions[i][1]
            });
            if(i == positions.length) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                callback();
                return;
            }
             i++;
        },
        300);
        return true;
    }
    Typer(function () {});

})
```

```css
.content{
    position:absolute;
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.blocks{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    background:wheat;
    color:gray;
    font-size:large;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:4px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="blocks" data-number="0">1</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="1">2</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="2">3</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="3">4</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="4">5</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="5">6</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="6">7</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="7">8</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="8">9</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-number="9">10</div>
</div>
```